# get php-nuke feeds

Tags: php, rss

I need to get RSS feed from website use **PHP-Nuke** ?

But this website is't mine , so I cannot add any addons or plugins

http://www.phpnuke.org/

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try http://feed43.com/ or http://page2rss.com/ or any of the other services which takes in any web url and puts out an RSS feed.

Answer (score 1):

If a feed doesn't exist you will have to [scrape](https://www.google.com/?q=php+web+scraping) it - however, any *actual* RSS feeds within websites are usually highlighted in the source code *<sup>(HTML)</sup>* for search engines to pick up.  Look for `<links/>` along the lines of the following example placed between the `<head/>` tags:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="[URL]"/>
```

For example in PHP-Nuke* sites, the default / unmodified installation has, since early versions contained a file in the root directory called `/backend.php` which outputs RSS.  This may contain the information you are looking for on the site in question.

---

* ***footnote:*** *I can't believe people are still using PHP-Nuke?! It was born over a decade ago when the internet elite were still telling us table-based layouts were the greatest thing since sliced bread!*